# How to diagnose Azure WebSite CPU usage increasing over time

Tags: azure, visual-studio-debugging, azure-web-app-service

I have a 1 Web Application inside 1 App Service on Azure.  The website has very low traffic (about 5 users).   If I restart the web application, over time (about a week) the CPU usage will go from from 0 to 100% gradually over the week.  Memory usage stays the same.  If you look at the chart of the App Service on Azure it is a near perfect linear increase.

I am unable to reproduce this issue in testing or through load simulation, it only occurs in production.  I've re-published the application, scaled up and down to create a new Azure instance, and it still does the same thing.

I tried to do a remote debugging session in Visual Studio, but I'm not sure how to go about determining where the problem.

Do you have any suggestions or guidance about how to remotely debug increasing CPU usage on Azure WebSites?

Answer (score 0):

I created a new App Service and moved the web application into the service, and that fixed it.